# Importing data to make a DateListPlot

Tags: import, string-manipulation

I am having a hard time trying to import some text data for later use in `DateListPlot`.  My first field in my data is a date of the format "yyyymmdd".  I tried to use both `ReadList` and `Import`, but I cannot get `DateListPlot` to understand that my date is truly a date.

```
data = 
 Import["/path/to/data.txt", "Table", "DateStringFormat" -> {"Year", "Month", "Day"}] //Short
```

> ```
> {{20131217, 123123.}, <<50>>, {20140313, 321321.}}
> ```

```
DateListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis]
```

> DateListPlot::ntdt: The first argument to DateListPlot should be a list of pairs of dates and real values, a list of real values, or a list of several such lists. >>

With `ReadList` I tried to see if I could use `StringSplit`, but that didn't seem to work either.

Any pointers would be most appreciated.

Edit: I added some more data.

```
data = Import[
"/path/to/file.txt", 
"Table", "DateStringFormat" -> {"Year", "Month", "Day"}] //TableForm

{
 {20131217, 114812.},
 {20131220, 114192.},
 {20131221, 114192.},
 {20131223, 114192.},
 {20131224, 114504.},
 {20131226, 115408.},
 {20131227, 115165.}
}
```

Comment: You may want to post a few lines of your txt file

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. With the two data points you have provided, I get perfectly good, if uninteresting, `DateListPlot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make the assumption that your imported data is of the form {{20131217, 123123.}, {20140313, 321321.},...}. If the date is a string then omit the `String` function in the following. You need to convert your imported into a date recognized by Mathematica.

```
DateListPlot[{DateList[ToString@#1], #2} & @@@ {{20131217, 
    123123.}, {20140313, 321321.}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", ", ", "Year"}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 400000}]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but received a similar error:  `DateListPlot[{DateList[ToString@#1], #2} & @@@ data, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", ", ", "Year"}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 400000}]`  DateList::str: "String \!\(\"{20131217, 114812.}\"\) cannot be interpreted as a date in format Automatic" DateListPlot::ntdt: The first argument to DateListPlot should be a list of pairs of dates and real values, a list of real values, or a list of several such lists

Comment: @sbank this critically depends on your data format. `DateList` just converts your date into a format Mathematica understands. If this failed try remove `ToString` as your first argument may be a string. Otherwise a hyerlink to a small sample of your data or  copying and pasting your imported data as an update for the question.

Comment: @sbank I have run code on pasted version of `data={
 {20131217, 114812.},
 {20131220, 114192.},
 {20131221, 114192.},
 {20131223, 114192.},
 {20131224, 114504.},
 {20131226, 115408.},
 {20131227, 115165.}
}` without problem. Note data should be list. You should remove `TableForm`.

Comment: Thanks!  it was the TableForm (or my use of //Short).  I thought that those arguments just changed the output for presentation purposes.  I did not think it would change the interpretation of the data.  Thanks so much.  I spent more hours on this than I would like to admit for something so trivial!

Comment: @sbank I am glad we have reached a positive resolution. We all have had similar experiences...the site helps pool and share it:)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to convert an integer of the form YYYYMMDD to a `DateObject`.  Eliminate the call to `ToString` if your data is a string.

```
dateNum = 20191220
date = DateObject[ToExpression /@ (StringTake[ToString[dateNum], #] & /@ {{1, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}})]
```

[image]

I subsequently discovered the following works too.  The empty strings represent the absence of date component separators, e.g. "/".

```
DateObject[DateList[{"20191220", {"Year", "", "Month", "", "Day"}}]]
```